# Netbeans Linux Less

Tags: css, linux, netbeans, less

Установил NetBeans под линукс, установил less, в командной строке

```
lessc style.less style.css
```

компилируется как нужно.

В NetBeans ошибка:

> INFO [org.netbeans.modules.css.prep.process.BaseProcessor]: Not
>   compiling, file
>   /var/www/{имяпроекта}/public_html/themes/default/less/style.less not
>   matched within current mappings [Pair[/less,/css]]

Пути в ошибке правильные, пробовал убирать слэши в настройках проекта NetBeans, прописывал полные пути и т.д..

> Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201)
>  Обновления:
>   Среда NetBeans IDE обновлена до версии NetBeans 8.1 Patch 1
>  Java:
>   1.8.0_101; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.101-b13
>  Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_101-b13
>  System: Linux
>   version 3.19.0-32-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; ru_RU

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась изменением путей
Исходные файлы у меня - /var/www/{имяпроекта}
Корневой узел в настройках - /var/www/{имяпроекта}/public_html

Пути поменял на следующие:
Ввод /themes/default/less
Ввод /themes/default/css

До этого тоже пробовал такие пути, но использовал рекомендуемую переменную ${web.root}, с ней не работало

Возможно кому-то пригодится